# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter'

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am trying to make a jQuery pagination work, and I'm including this javascript file which triggers it.

```
<script src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Chrome shows the file is loaded, however the pagination clicks don't work. I go into the console and I get this annoying little error which I have no idea how to solve. The class is there :/

[image]

Here's the HTML with the class...

```
<table id="tabledlist" class="tablesorter" width="920px" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
..thead, th, tbody, tr, td and so on...
</table>

<div align="right" id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
            <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/pagination/first.png" class="first" />
            <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/pagination/prev.png" class="prev" />
            <input align="middle" type="text" class="pagedisplay" size="5"/>
            <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/pagination/next.png" class="next" />
            <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/pagination/last.png" class="last" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And just below it, I included this...

```
<script defer="defer">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
            $("#tabledlist")
            .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
    } 
    ); 
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include the `tablesorter` plugin first? You seem to have the `pager` "add-on"... (not sure if this is a dumb/obvious question of mine). `jquery.tablesorter.pager.js` doesn't include the `tablesorter` jQuery plugin, you have to include that yourself before the `pager` add-on. The fact that the error says "has no method `tablesorter`" makes me think this...

Comment: That's probably why :/ I'm just dumb, I didn't know you needed them both. Any idea where I could get this file?

Comment: Have you checked with Devtools under "Sources" and see if the scripts was loaded?

Comment: @zzwyb89 No problem, it's a little mistake :) The library is in http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.zip . So you will include the jQuery library, then this library, then the pager add-on. Take a look at the documentation for the plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ . If you scroll down to the "Download" section, you'll see the link for the .zip I just gave, as well as the pager add-on and some other things as well.

Comment: Thank you Ian. It's all working :)

Comment: @zzwyb89 No problem, glad it helped! I added an answer, even though you know now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery is complaining that `tablesorter` is not a valid method, that means that the `tablesorter` plugin doesn't seem to be included/loaded.

The jQuery `tablesorter` plugin is required in order to use its `pager` add-on. To do this, visit the documentation and scroll to the "Download" section: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ . There is the download for the `tablesorter`, as well as the `pager` add-on, and some other items.

You will then need to include the scripts as something like this, depending on the file names you save them as, but most importantly in this order:

```
<script src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And from there, you can use the `.tablesorter()` method on jQuery objects.